# changing the default keybindings of the Ace editor

Tags: ace-editor

I'm using the vim mode and would like to change the behavior of 'j' to 'gj' and 'k' to 'gk'. I tried using the following:

> editor.commands.bindKey("j", null);
>   editor.commands.bindKey("j", "golinedown");

But 'j' still has the default behavior of going to the next line in the file (rather than the next line on screen). As a workaround, I'm currently using:

> editor.commands.bindKey("cmd-j", "golinedown");

which works since cmd-j isn't used for anything else. How can I change the default key binding for 'j','k'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vim keybindings have different format than the default ace keybinding, and because of that they use their own api  `Vim.map` similar to the `:map` command in vim

```
Vim = require("ace/keyboard/vim").Vim
Vim.map("j", "gj", "normal")
Vim.map("k", "gk", "normal")
```

Note that vim keybinding is not included in ace.js and is loaded asynchronously, so you need to run this code after that file is loaded, which can be done either by loading the `keybinding-vim.js` script, using `config.loadModule`

```
ace.config.loadModule("ace/keybinding/vim", function() {
    // use Vim here
})
```

or adding a listener for "load.module" event

```
ace.config.on("load.module", function(e) { 
   if (e.name == "ace/keyboard/vim" && e.module.Vim) 
       // use Vim here
})
```

Comment: Thanks! But now the first line is giving me a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Vim' of undefined".

Comment: I've edited the answer to describe how Vim can be loaded